# Minimal rotational degrees of freedom needed in N-space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, rotations, word-problem

How many rotational matrices are needed in N-space to achieve an arbitrary attitude when allowed to be successively applied?

Each N by N rotation matrix will allow only a rotation in a plane, so only two dimensions may be selected for rotation at a time. What is a smallest set of these matrices which, when used in succession, can achieve any desired orientation in N space?

Assume an N dimensional hypercube with distinct features at every vertex is being rotated on a computer screen under control of $m$ sense switches. The idea is to minimize the number of switches without sacrificing the ability to orient the object, whose projection appears on the screen, in any desired attitude, eventually, by application of this minimal set of rotations.

So far I have $m=N-1$. This is the set comprised of the set of rotations that all include the $x$ dimension.  Is there a smaller set? Perhaps not. But the real question is:

If we open it up to allow multiple dimensions being rotated per switch, does that change the answer?

Comment: Generally the number of degrees of freedom for  N-dimensional rotation matrix is the same as the number of DOF for skew-symmetric N-dimensional matrix so we have $n(n-1)/2$ DOF.

Comment: Thank you. So for four dimensions, 6?

Comment: But I already proved I need only 3, xy, xz, and xw.

Comment: By using these three in sequences I can achieve any final orientation. The question is not about degrees of freedom. It is about the minimal number of rotation matrices to cover the space if orientations when sequences of these rotations are allowed.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure whether we can omit planes yz,yw,wz - with three mentioned by you it gives 6 planes for 4D. $   \ \ \  \ \ \ $  In 3 dimensions we could have three  (=(3*2)/2) planes xy,yz,zx.

Comment: In three dimensions you need 2. Xy and xz. If you are keeping your view of xy on screen, rotate the object in the xz plane by 90 degrees. Now you see on screen what was on the z axis appear on your x axis. You can now rotate xy to effect what would have been yz rotation. Rotations are not ABOUT the perpendicular axis, they happen IN a pair of dimensions.

Comment: I rotate hypercubes since 1969 on computers. You just pick two dimensions for your rotation matrix. ALL other coordinates are not changed.

Comment: I have always used $N-1$ different rotation matrices for rotating N-cube. I am wondering, if I used combinations of rotations within a single matrix, then that number could be reduced?

Comment: Maybe we understand "orientation" differently. In 3D to obtain any orientantion of the solid body we need 3 rotations, with rotations in xy,xz,zy planes by so called Euler angles. It is a well known result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles. But orientation is understood here as a whole frame attached to the body.But if you choose to describe orientation by a single vector what is equivalent by the  point on the sphere (which can be described with two coordinates) then really we need only two rotations but a body located on the sphere can also rotate..

Comment: So the main problem lies here in what we mean by "an arbitrary attitude".

Comment: Not a single vector, but the three lines perpendicular to the faces of the 3-cube passing thru the origin about which the cube is always centered. Don’t forget that as many successive rotations as needed to obtain an arbitrary orientation are allowed.

Comment: Aha, I see. they can be rotations in plane XY,XZ and then XY. Yes in this case it's ZYZ convention of Euler angles. You are right, I was thinking  that you are talking about only two succesive rotations with two rotation matrices ... at the case of more rotations your reasoning is absolutely correct.. however I suspect that although we have only 3 matrices for 4D, the number of operations should be at least 6 in general case..

Comment: Would you believe I proved N-1 years ago. I can’t find the proof but it was only a page. Basically you can rotate any of the “missing” rotations into an orientation needed.

Comment: It's very interesting, thank you very much for all these explanations, inspired by you now I wonder is it possible to build a robot in 4D grasping 4D cubes..

Comment: I think a 4-d ray tracing program would be nice. And yes you could do that. You are welcome. Love to chat in one of the rooms about what to do next sometime.